# I need help selecting views from MySQL and load it onto another server. Python keeps trying to get data from destination server instead of source

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I'm trying to select data from a view in a MySQL server to load into another MySQL server (due to company policy I can't modify the source server or even use mysqldump to get the data out). I think I got pretty close but I ran into a problem. Basically View_A in Database_A is the data I'm trying to select and get loaded into the destination server which is View_B in Database_B. However when I ran the code, Python keeps trying to get data from the Database_B instead if Database_A. It would say that Table Database_B.View_A doesn't exist. While it's supposed to be getting data from View A in Database A. I hope I'm explaining that ok. I included the code that I used, please let me know if I did anything wrong. I'm new to Python so forgive me if I made some stupid mistake. Thank you so much!

PS: I also have some warnings saying that my cursors and connections can be undefined if that helps.

```
import mysql.connector

source_db_config = {
    'host': "123.456.789",
    'user': "user1",
    'password': "passwrd",
    'database': "Database_A"
}

destination_db_config = {
    'host': "987.654.321",
    'user': "user2",
    'password': "passwrd2",
    'database': "Database_B"
}
try:
    source_connection = mysql.connector.connect(**source_db_config)
        if source_connection.is_connected():
        source_cursor = source_connection.cursor()

        source_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM View_A")
        rows = source_cursor.fetchall()

        destination_connection = mysql.connector.connect(**destination_db_config)
        if destination_connection.is_connected():
            destination_cursor = destination_connection.cursor()

            create_view_query = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW View_B AS SELECT * FROM View_A"
            destination_cursor.execute(create_view_query)
            destination_connection.commit()

except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

finally:
    if 'source_cursor' in locals():
        source_cursor.close()
    if 'source_connection' in locals() and source_connection.is_connected():
        source_connection.close()
    if 'destination_cursor' in locals():
        destination_cursor.close()
    if 'destination_connection' in locals() and destination_connection.is_connected():
        destination_connection.close()
```